# jQuery; Perform function after loading iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe

I want to perform some functions on iframe.
However, the functions does not work when the page is loaded.

I suppose that the functions are triggered before iframe elements are rendered.
Either `$(window).load` or `$(document).ready` perform before iframe are set up.

So, I would like to ask how to perform jQuery functions after iframe elements are rendered.

My source code is like this;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    doSomething($("ID of iframe"));
});
```

`$("iframe").ready()` does not work either. In addition, I would like to apply this function for not all iframe fields, so `$("iframe").each()` is not appropriate.

I already read and tried these questions, but any of them did not work.

[Wait for iframe to load in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463581/wait-for-iframe-to-load-in-javascript)

[Making script wait until iframe has loaded before running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17436881/making-script-wait-until-iframe-has-loaded-before-running)

[Wait for iframe to load before next function is triggered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15099537/wait-for-iframe-to-load-before-next-function-is-triggered)

Comment: `$('#id-of-iframe').load()` definitely works...

Comment: `$("iframe").load` does not work, unfortunately. I inserted `console.log` inside the `$("iframe").load`, but it is not performed either.

Comment: You can use the on function: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10920355/attaching-click-event-to-a-jquery-object-not-yet-added-to-the-dom